# Receiver in manifest file is giving error class or interface expected

Tags: java, android, manifest

There is an error in the manifest file that when I try to enter reciever it says class or interface expected

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.uzairaslam.silenter" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS_" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"/>
```

The receiver class which is not added is this

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
String d ;
String deviceard;
String roomard ;
boolean status ;
public AlarmReceiver() {

}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    d= intent.getStringExtra("DeviceId");
    deviceard = intent.getStringExtra("Device_Ard_Id");
    roomard = intent.getStringExtra("Room_Ard_id");
    status = Boolean.parseBoolean(intent.getStringExtra("Device_Status"));

    if(status)
        Send_sms("y"+roomard+":"+deviceard+":oz" ,context);
    else
        Send_sms("y"+roomard+":"+deviceard+":fz" ,context);

    Toast.makeText(context,"Mateen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

public void Send_sms(String msg,Context c)
{
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(c, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();


}
```

}

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, Uzair?

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"/>
```

This line should be with in the **application** tag and give the fully qualified Receiver name. like below

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="<receiver package>.AlarmReceiver"/>

</application>
```

Comment: I did that too but no success

Comment: @UzairAnsari when you did it like that what is the error ?

Comment: It was the same error "class or interface expected"

Comment: @UzairAnsari can you add your `AlarmReceiver` class, i need to determine which action you are using in your `Receiver` ?

Comment: First add fully qualified receiver name

Comment: @Prasad what is meant by fully qualified receiver name?

Comment: If the receiver is in the same directory as main package directory simply put dot before receiver name

Comment: Fully qualified means with the package name like <receiver packagename>.AlarmReceiver

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I have added the receiver class

Comment: @Prasad the receiver class is in the same package

Comment: So put the dot before AlarmReceiver like <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>